# Embedding SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm working with sql server ce database and C#, and I wondering how to really embed the database file so when I have finish installing the app I don't need to copy-paste the database file to the environment as I set in the following code :

```
 private void sambung()
    {
        string lokasifile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\compactedition.sdf";
        string stringkoneksi = "Data Source = \"" + lokasifile + "\";Password = 'blablabla'; Encrypt = True";
        koneksi = new SqlCeConnection(stringkoneksi);
    }
```

Do you have any suggestion to make it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to provide a `.sdf` file with data already in it? Or could you just use the [`SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.createdatabase%28v=vs.100%29) call to create an empty `.sdf` database for you?

Comment: ya i need to provide .sdf file with data, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy your database to root directory or upper you can use relative path like this:

```
public static string GetLogicBinDebug()
    {
        string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        return Path.Combine(baseDir, @"..\..\database.sdf");
    }
```

Or you can keep connection string in app.config using relative path:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dbEDMContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/dbEDM.csdl|res://*/dbEDM.ssdl|res://*/dbEDM.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\..\..\yourDB.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ will point to "bin" folder

**
If you are asking about how to copy database file to your application folder, you can use this approach:

Include Database file to your project in Visual Studio, open file properties and 
set **Build action** to "**Content**",
**Copy to output directory** - "**copy if newer**" or "**copy always**"

Comment: `return Path.Combine(baseDir, @"Data Source=D:\\Code Bunch\\Visual Studio 2010\\project\\project\\bin\\Debug\\database.sdf");`
well should it be like that??

Comment: - no, your example is hardcoded. This method is defined to acquire full path to database depending on your application start up path. Example: your DB located on `C:\DataBase.sdf`. Your application is installed on `C:\Program Files\Application\App.exe`. Use `Path.Combine(baseDir, @"\..\..\..\DataBase.sdf")` to get full path to your DB.